# Angular - Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5

I'm trying to use a simple Angular function in my Laravel 5 project and I keep getting this error:

> angular is not defined

I have tried to move `angular.min.js` to the top making it the first JS script on my index page but it still doesn't work.

This is my code: [pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/Zt2ru7y9)

It only outputs `{{name}}` and not the actual string from the controller!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this issue before. In my case it was due to the incorrect relative reference i was using. I am not an expert in this matter but i would recommend you to try with different combinations and see if it helps. Also see where the js folder is placed in your website hierarchy

Ex. src="js/angular.min.js"
or
src="../js/angular.min.js"

Comment: Thank you! i changede from "/js/angular.min.js" to "js/angular.min.js" and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

You script tags are wrapped in a conditional IE tag.

`<!--[if lt IE 9]>`

Place your angular script tag outside of that and you'll be fine.

Comment: it didnt work :( I even put the script at the top of the <head> tag

Answer (score 0):

If you've downloaded the angular.js file from Google, you need to make sure that everyone has Read access to it, or it will not be loaded by your HTML file. By default, it seems to download with No access permissions.